# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'messages') (forms AJAX POST)

Tags: forms, ajax

Here I have created a custom module, which has one form in it...An ajax response is called when an Email is entered in form field and it will callback an HTML response.

I have tested this code on my localhost and my own test website I havent seen this error but when i installed my module in main website i could this error...

Here is the error from console.

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: If there is a custom module we will have to see some of the code. Disable JavaScript aggregation to see the actual file names in the stack trace.

Comment: Hello @cilefen thank you for your reply... The error is in Clientside_validation(version 3.0.0 rc4) module .. exactly in clientside_validation_jquery/js/cv.jquery.validate.js.  ; 
 In line -> e.extend(e.validator.messages, t.clientside_validation_jquery.messages); error is happening

Comment: It seems this is a bug report: https://www.drupal.org/project/clientside_validation/issues/3211333

Comment: Yeah.. error is cleared when i installed new version(3.0.1) thank you for the Disable JS aggregation idea ..